# Moved Magento Installation, rm'd the parent folder and recreated it, after MV back blank site

Tags: magento2

We are having a file structure like the following:

```
 - public_html
 - - otherVersion/
 - - Magento File Structure
 - - Magento Files
```

After I did the movement with `$ mv public_html/otherVersion .`

I did the remove with `rm -rf public_html/*`. And after a movement back with `$ mv otherVersion public_html/` the Magento Installation in otherVersion/ is nonfunctional.

I looked for broken symlinks, only a few in otherVersion/pub/static/backend/..., but I deleted those and hoped for a new generation of them, but it didnt worked.

php bin/magento doesn't work as well. A chmod-reset didn't helped here, too.

The logs don't contain anything.

We are using Magento 2.0.6.

What did I wrong, or how can I fix this?

Meanwhile, I got an step forward. I dumped the autoload with `php composer.phardump-autoload`, and I so I got this message:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Constant name is expected. in /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Constant.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/App/Arguments/ArgumentInterpreter.php(35): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Constant->evaluate(Array) #1 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ArgumentInterpreter->evaluate(Array) #2 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Mapper/Dom.php(101): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array) #3 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(168): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Mapper\Dom->convert(Object(DOMDocument)) #4 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(127): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator)) #5 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(269): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('primary') #6 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(137): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->_loadPrimaryConfig(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList), Object(Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverPool), Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Mapper\Dom), 'developer') #7 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(385): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array) #8 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(232): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->initObjectManager() #9 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\\Framewo...') #10 {main} Next Magento\Framework\Exception\State\InitException: Constant name is expected. in /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php:271 Stack trace: #0 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(137): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->_loadPrimaryConfig(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList), Object(Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverPool), Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Mapper\Dom), 'developer') #1 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(385): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array) #2 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(232): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->initObjectManager() #3 /home/user/public_html/importantFolder/index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\\Framewo...') #4 {main}
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the contents of the var/cache, var/generation, and var/view_preprocessed directories?

Comment: I did it right now, but check the update!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Anyhow I have overwritten the vendor-Files of the important Folder (not sure how - will investigate).

However, I had to reinstall the magento version I've used.

First of all, add your current magento version to composer, I did with:
`php-cli composer.phar require magento/product-community-edition 2.0.6 --no-update`. After that, do `php-cli composer.phar update`. and let it go through. Dont forget the `--no-update`, since it fixes bugs with the file locking due to the update.